# Sort an array A using Quick Sort. Using reccursion

Tags: quicksort

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

    
    void quickSort(int input[], int start, int end)
    {
            // your code goes here 
    }
    void quickSort(int input[], int size)
    {
            quickSort(input, 0, size - 1);
    }
        
*/
void swap(int* a,int* b){
    int temp=*a;
    *a=*b;
    *b=temp;
}
int count(int input[],int start,int end ){
    static int c=0;
    if(start==end)
        return c;
    if(input[start]>input[end])
        c++;
    return count(input,start,end-1);
}
int partionArray(int input[],int start,int end ){
    int c=count(input,start,end);
    int pi=c+start;
    swap(&input[start],&input[pi]);
    int i=start;
    int j=end;
    while(i<pi&&j>pi)
    {
        if(input[i]<input[pi])
        {
            i++;
        }
        else if(input[j]>=input[pi])
        {
            j--;
        }
        else
        {
            swap(&input[i],&input[j]);
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
    return pi;
}
void qs(int input[],int start, int end){
    if(start>=end)
        return;
    int pi=partionArray(input,start,end);
    qs(input,start,pi-1);
    qs(input,pi+1,end);
}
void quickSort(int input[], int size) {
    qs(input,0,size-1);

}

int main(){
    int n;
    cin >> n;
  
    int *input = new int[n];
    
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> input[i];
    }
    
    quickSort(input, n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << input[i] << " ";
    }
    
    delete [] input;

}
```

Sort an array A using Quick Sort. Using reccursion is the question.
Input format :
Line 1 : Integer n i.e. Array size
Line 2 : Array elements (separated by space)
Output format :
Array elements in increasing order (separated by space)
Constraints :
1 <= n <= 10^3

What did i do wrong in this code pls can any one explain?Is every thing right with this code?

Comment: What is issue or error please specify

Comment: i am getting run time error what did i do wrong